# Primary monitor turns off when it's input source changes, and does not turn back on

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, monitor, nvidia-settings

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a GTX 1080 GPU with the Nvidia Driver Version 440.100

That being said, I have a two monitor setup:

- Monitor LG: 2560 x 1080 (primary) (DisplayPort)
- Monitor Samsung: 1920 x 1080 (secondary) (DVI)

The monitors are joined together, everything works properly until I change the primary monitor input source to HDMI, so that I can play a console for example.

When I switch the monitor input source back to the PC one (DisplayPort), the screen has no signal as if the computer was not connected (instead of recognizing the monitor again, which is what it should do).

If I check the Nvidia X Server Settings afterwards, I can see that it appears as OFF and resolution is set to Off as well. If I set those to the proper values the primary monitor gets image again and gets fixed, but as you would understand this is tedious to do every time it happens.

Is there any known way to fix this behavior? It's very annoying... Thank you so much in advance, let me know if you need more system info!

Answer (score 1):

A downgrade from the Nvidia driver version 440.400 to 435.21 fixed the problem!